# Python3 and Pillow (PIL) - Add an image on top of other image with transparency

Tags: python-3.x, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am creating a script in which the script gets 2 images. First image is the background image and the second one is the overlay image to be displayed on top of the first image but with almost 90% transparency.

I have the following code:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\web\\2.jpg', 'r')
img_w, img_h = img.size

img.putalpha(200)

background = Image.open('C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\web\\email.jpg', 'r')
bg_w, bg_h = background.size
offset = ((bg_w - img_w) // 2, (bg_h - img_h) // 2)
background.paste(img, offset)
background.save('C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\out.png')
```

Now, the issue is, that the `img.putalpha(200)` does not do anything at all, even though it was supposed to give me transparency of the image.

How can I achieve to place the overlay image and then modify it's transparency in Python?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a third parameter as `mask` for the [paste()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.paste).

I used these 2 images:

[image]
[image]

Here's the complete code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image

# Open overlay image
img = Image.open('good.jpg')
img_w, img_h = img.size

img.putalpha(128)

background = Image.open('paddington.jpg')
bg_w, bg_h = background.size
offset = ((bg_w - img_w) // 2, (bg_h - img_h) // 2)
background.paste(img, offset, img)
background.save('result.png')
```

[image]

And if I revert to the original code:

```
background.paste(img, offset)
```

[image]

Comment: This fixed my issue! Thank you very much! Much appreciated :)

Comment: Cool, glad it worked for you. Good luck with your project!